# How to drop item to empty section in react-dnd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd, sortablejs

I'm trying to make a drag and drop list using `react-dnd`.

I have a part-working example: [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dnd-sortable-grid-multiple-groups-6lkwn)

I have a one issue here:

I can't drop an item in an empty section.

If we move `image1` to first or third group, we can't go back to second group. We also can't drop item to the last position of the group (we need to set a position other than the last one and then move to the last one), but I think these problems are related.

I suspect the problem lies here, in `DragItem.js`:

```
export default DropTarget(Types.FILE, fileTarget, (connect, monitor) => ({
  connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
  isOver: monitor.isOver(),
  isOverCurrent: monitor.isOver({ shallow: true }),
  canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
  itemType: monitor.getItemType()
}))(DragSource(Types.FILE, cardSource, collect)(DragItem));
```

DragSource and DropTarget are the same component, so if section has not any item in itself, it's not DrogTarget there.

When I tried to move the item higher to `Project.js`, the whole section (with all the elements inside) was one element to Drag, this is also not a solution.

Any ideas? Or maybe i have to use different tool to this task?

Comment: just make the empty section too a droptarget

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using your draggable cards as droppable containers (so no card, nowhere to drop).

The way I used `react-dnd` before was creating droppable containers with the hook useDrop [ract-dnd use drop](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/use-drop) so for this case I would make your `<div className="files-container">` into a droppable container. That should allow you to drop cards into empty containers.

Answer (score 0):

Finnally I decided to use a different package to solve this problem. Instead `react-dnd` I used `react-sortablejs`. It is easier to implement in this case and meets my all expectations in this task.

Working example: [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-rain-k7hqi)

Thanks!